# Read a file uploaded with Struts

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

I try to read a file which is uploaded through browsing. For that i am using apache commons fileupload jar. So before run it with the project application i simply do a servlet/jsp POC project which successfully reads the file. Below is the code,

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        boolean isMultipart = FileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        String content = "";

        try {
            if (isMultipart) {
                FileItemFactory factory = new DefaultFileItemFactory();
                FileUploadBase upload = new FileUpload(factory);
                String[] arr;
                List items;

                items = upload.parseRequest(request);

                Iterator iter = items.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        BufferedInputStream buff = new    BufferedInputStream(
                                item.getInputStream());
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buff.available()];
                        buff.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        content = new String(bytes);
                        arr = content.split(",");

                    }
                }
            }

            request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request,
                    response);
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {

        }
```

I have use the jar version 1.1 becuase my project directory has that version of the jar and it use java 1.4. With java 1.5 we suppose to use ServletFileUpload instead of FileUpload . But i guess that does not matter where i can do the work with ealier version of jar.

The problem comes when i use it with the real application which use struts 1.1. All seems fine but i dont return items when parsing the request.

items = upload.parseRequest(request);

**items is empty here.**

So the difference i can find is that POC project which successfull show result is a JSP/Servlet project where the real application is using Struts.

Is the request going to be differe in JSP/Servlet and Struts project in this case?

In both case i use below in the form.

```
<form action="SampleWeb" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Below is the only addition in the struts application,

```
    <action
        path="/ReportsAction"
        type="come.test.ReportsAction"
        name="ReportsForm"
        scope="request"
        validate="false"
        parameter="dispatch">
        <forward name="success" path="/reports/A.jsp"/>
        <forward name="updatesuccess" path="/common/B.jsp"/>              
    </action>
```

Comment: Was the file sent correctly to the server (view the post request in your browser's developer tools)?

Comment: yes both request are identical. It sends the files content as post parameters.                                                         Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile"; filename="sample.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
564447000,563000240,563178000,563143000

Answer (score 1):

A request is a request.

However, if you're using Struts 1, actually *use* Struts 1.

**The Form, Java Side**

Use an `ActionForm` with a `FormFile` property:

```java
public class YourForm extends ActionForm {
private FormFile file; // Plus public getter/setter
    // Etc.
}
```

You can also do things like validate the content type:

```java
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (!"text/plain".equals(getFile().getContentType())) {
        // etc.
```

**The Form, JSP Side**

```xml
<html:form action="/uploadAction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <html:file property="file" />
  <!-- Etc... -->
```

**The Action**

In the action you should copy your file to its final destination (*outside* the webapp; use a configuration parameter to define where files end up at). Consider using a utility library to do the copy (or move, maybe, there are several options) instead of doing all the work in the action as shown in some tutorials.

http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-file-upload-example/

Don't blindly use the same techniques across environments: this work is handled *for* you.

Also, avoid using Struts 1 for new projects. It's quite old and much more difficult to use than more modern options like Struts 2 or Spring MVC (which in turn are more difficult to use than things like Rails, Grails, Play, etc.)

Comment: I was able to read the file with using struts file property. <form-property name="strUploadFile"    type="org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile"/>                          But it surprise why the normal request parsing not work. Even as i mentioned the post request are also identical in both projects

Comment: @Harshana Because multipart requests are different, and you need to parse them differently instead of grabbing parmeters out of the request. For example, using Apache Commons FileUpload.

Comment: yes yes my example use that. Then  upload.parseRequest(request); returns null with correct post request with file content as parameters (i inspect the request)

Comment: @Harshana If you're using Struts you don't *need* to do that manually, and Struts has already parsed the request, meaning it's likely it's not parseable *again* (nor would there be a need to). I don't understand what you're doing at this point.

Comment: NO i have tried two different approches. 1. Using apache commons fileupload jar as shown in above example, Where i have not set form property like below,<form-property name="strUploadFile" type="org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile"/> 2. Using struts by setting the form property and access the file content as BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     ((FormFile) actionForm.get("strUploadFile"))
       .getInputStream()));

Comment: when using number 1 approach which the commons fileupload jar, according to that API's i need to parse the request and get the items which returns null. No struts file upload behavior involve in this approach. List items = upload.parseRequest(request);

Comment: As if u say struts alreay parse the request, then how can i directly get the items lits which includes the file upload item too using apache commons fileupload

Comment: @Harshana: did you understand how to avoid struts request parsing?